# Allow window overlap in awesome WM floating mode?

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm

I am trying to set up a tag in awesome that contains a web browser and tyrs (command line twitter client), where both programs overlap each other following the geometries I have set to them.  (This tag is closer to a traditional, non-tiling WM as I don't like to tile these particular programs). However, awesome will always move one window to a corner of the screen if the other is open, as though it is trying to stop them from overlapping.

Is there any way to override this behaviour so that it will always open both of these windows in the positions I have set, no matter what else is currently open in the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Shifty](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Shifty) for this, and configure some apps (vlc, pidgin, skype) to stay always floating and on all tags.  You can also limit them to a specific tag:

```
shifty.config.apps = {}
    ...
    {
        match = {"app1", "app2", "app3"},
        float = true,
    },
    {
        match = {"app2"},
        geometry = {100, 100, nil, nil},
    },
    ...
}
```

You can also configure `shifty.config.tags` to create a tag with float tiling.